# button item lost when hide and unhide toolbar

Tags: iphone, uibarbuttonitem

i dont know, why the button are disappear after the toolbar set to hide and unhide.
how can i fix it?

setup a button code

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    //NSLog(@"viewDidAppear ");

    [self becomeFirstResponder];
    //Create a button
    UIBarButtonItem *back = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                        initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRewind 
                target:self action:@selector(goback:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *fixspace1 = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                                 initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace 
                                 target:self action:nil];

    UIBarButtonItem *next = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFastForward 
                             target:self action:@selector(gofwd:)];
    UIBarButtonItem *stop = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemStop 
                             target:self action:@selector(stopload:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *refresh = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] 
                             initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemRefresh 
                             target:self action:@selector(refreshWeb:)];


    [self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixspace1, back, fixspace1, stop, fixspace1, next, fixspace1, nil] animated:YES];
    [self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:refresh animated:YES];

    [self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.navigationController.toolbar];

    [stop release];
    [next release];
    [back release];
    [refresh release];
    [fixspace1 release];
}
```

and i setup my button at this method

```
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

this code use for hide toolbar

```
    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
```

[image]

Comment: Can you post your code in which you show the button? That is your viewDidAppear method

Comment: What is the purpose of this line:   
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.navigationController.toolbar];
It appears to be either redundant or downright wrong.  Documentation says that the toolbar is "For use when presenting an action sheet", which I don't believe you are doing.  Even then, I can't see why you would need to ADD it to the view.

Comment: ok i remove it! agree with you

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The [documented method](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW30) for setting toolbar items is **via the toolbarItems property of the view controller**. The [same UINavigationController Reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UINavigationController_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40006934-CH3-SW24) also lists the `toolbar` property as read-only and specifically warns

> You should not modify the UIToolbar
>   object directly.

Therefore, try changing

```
[self.navigationController.toolbar setItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixspace1, back, fixspace1, stop, fixspace1, next, fixspace1, nil] animated:YES];
```

to

```
[self setToolbarItems:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:fixspace1, back, fixspace1, stop, fixspace1, next, fixspace1, nil] animated:YES];
```

Comment: thanks David Gelhar it work, my button are back after it hide!

Comment: Great answer...saved me 20 mins I'm sure :)

Answer (score 1):

Seeing no better answers, I'll promote my earlier comment.  Try taking out this line:

```
[self.navigationController.view addSubview:self.navigationController.toolbar];
```

I haven't experimented with anything like that but it looks wrong and very much against the iPhone SDK philosophy.  If the controller object already has a pointer to the toolbar, why would you need to add it to the view?  If that's the right place for it, the controller object would do that itself.

Comment: thanks Amagrammer, you are right about that line, but when i hide and unhide toolbar, my button are disappear how can i call them back?

Comment: Please show us the code you use to hide AND unhide.

Also, if the toolbar is in the navigation bar, you probably don't have to hide both -- just the nav bar.

Comment: this code use for hide toolbar

    [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
    [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];

Comment: ...and unhide?  That's the one I really need to see.

Comment: if (toggle) {
  
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:YES animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:YES animated:YES];
  self.navigationController.hidesBottomBarWhenPushed = YES;
  
 }
 else {
  [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController setNavigationBarHidden:NO animated:YES];
  [self.navigationController setToolbarHidden:NO animated:YES];
 }

Comment: I'd consider removing the hide&unhide of the toolbar itself.  If it's attached to the navigation bar, it presumably hides& unhides along with it.  Not sure about that though.

Answer (score 0):

I doub't that you should release your toolbar buttons immediately after adding them to the toolbar. You should save them in instance variables and release them in your `dealloc`.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with that part of it.  The navigation controller keeps references to them, and that's enough.